# Serverless GCP function whitelist cloud scheduler ip

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm wondering how to extend [this GCP HTTP example](https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/google-python-simple-http-endpoint) to only be callable by a Google Cloud Scheduler IP address or some way to limit it to being called from inside the specific GCP project.

Maybe the easiest would be some sort of resource or network config block in the `serverless.yml` but just not quite sure how to go about it and could not really find an example in the examples repository.

Comment: Do you want to do this with serverless framework? Or can you use gcloud directly? Or terraform?

Comment: Was wanting to use serverless but also am looking into terraform and thinking maybe that might be better option as could do the function and scheduler job in one place.

Answer (score 1):

I actually think in this case it makes more sense for me to create a pub sub function and then use pub sub messages via the scheduler to trigger the function.

My main worry was a http endpoint that could be public. The pub sub approach side steps this altogether.